# CORS errors when react gets redirected to login page

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger

I am getting the following error messages:
-Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/google due to access control checks
-Failed to load resource: Cross-origin redirection to https://accounts.google... denied by CORS policy: Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

I made a Kotlin-SpringBoot API and I'm in the process of developing a front end in React-TypeScript.
I used SwaggerCodegen to import the functions to interact with my API with OpenAPI docs.

I want my users to be authenticated with google OAUTH, so I decided to use Spring Security to make all my endpoints need authentication. I did it using this class:

```
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()

    }
}
```

Now, the api is in port 8080 and the frontend is on 3000
So if I access localhost:8080/restricted I get prompted to login and it works as expected.
But if my frontend on localhost:3000 tries to retrieve any data from the API I thought It'd just redirect  me anyways, but I get the CORS error above.
I have looked everywhere and just want to know if my approach is conceptually wrong or how I can authorize this type of redirecting (or if I even should).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: have you given `CORS` Access to your  `localhost:8080` from backend ?

Comment: I have tried the CrossOrigin anotation in my controller, without any effect, is that what you mean? I am fairly new to the whole oauth redirect thing..